# Jenkins Credentials / Is it possible to establish a ssh connection without private key

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am working on a pipeline project on Jenkins and Git and I was wondering if it was possible to establish an SSH connection credential only with username and password. That mean without a group of private and public key.

I see nobody doing it while It seems theorically possible so I'm asking the question

Thanks in advance,

Taeith

Answer (score 1):

You can with [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps). Here's example how to use it with credentials stored in `Credentials`

```
stage ('SSH') {
    steps {
        script{
            remote = [:]
            remote.name = "name"
            remote.host = "host_name_or_ip"
            remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            remote.failOnError = true
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_credentials', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {
                remote.user = username
                remote.password = password
                sshCommand remote: remote, command: "some_command"
           }
        }
    }
}
```